Calling LAPACK through Pybind crashes
I am writing a simple function to calculate log determinate in C++ using LAPACK. I write a unit test in C++, and it works fine. But when I use pybind and call this function in python with the same matrix, the program died at info = LAPACKE_dgetrf(LAPACK_COL_MAJOR, n, n, A, lda, ipiv);. Is there any difference between calling a function from C++ and from Python? How to fix this?
inline double logdet_chol(const Eigen::MatrixXd& M) {
    int n = M.rows();
    int lda = n;
    int info = 0;

    double* A = new double[n * n];
    std::copy(M.data(), M.data() + n * n, A);

    // Cholesky decomposition
    info = LAPACKE_dpotrf(LAPACK_COL_MAJOR, 'L', n, A, lda);
    if (info != 0) {
        // If Cholesky decomposition fails, use LU decomposition (LAPACKE_dgetrf)
        int* ipiv = new int[n];
        std::fill(ipiv, ipiv + n, 0);
        std::copy(M.data(), M.data() + n * n, A);

        info = LAPACKE_dgetrf(LAPACK_COL_MAJOR, n, n, A, lda, ipiv);

        if (info != 0) {
            delete[] ipiv;
            throw std::runtime_error("LU decomposition failed.");
        }

        double ld = 0.0;
        double sign = 1.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            ld += std::log(std::abs(A[i * lda + i]));
            if (A[i * lda + i] < 0) {
                sign = -sign;
            }
        }

        // Compute the determinant of the permutation matrix
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            if (ipiv[i] != i + 1) {
                sign = -sign;
            }
        }

        delete[] ipiv;

        if (sign <= 0) {
            return -std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
        }

        return ld;
    }
    // If Cholesky decomposition is successful, compute the log determinant
    double ld = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        ld += std::log(A[i * lda + i]);
    }

    return 2.0 * ld;
}

My test matrix is:
np.diag([1089.942113770775, 1010.096696063498, 58.66178651250262, 5661.020957489456, -1589555826.24471, -3799865302.243693, -162987547.4735685, -1771081.02947091, 255.3627654232152, 151.2319507163488])

I tried cout everywhere and the program just suddenly stop output from line info = LAPACKE_dgetrf(LAPACK_COL_MAJOR, n, n, A, lda, ipiv); in Python. It works fine in C++, so debug result in nothing.
================================UPDATE================================
Sorry about not providing a c++ test case. I am using a self made data structure in my program and I just use Eigen for pybind. I used to use Eigen for data struct and computation, but having lots of creation for small VecXd/MatXd, it was really slow. When replacing Eigen with my Mat(defined below) and Lapack, this problem occurred.
This test case works fine.
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <pybind11/eigen.h>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

template <typename T>
struct Mat{
  T* data=nullptr;
  size_t rows=0;
  size_t cols=0;
};

inline double logdet_chol(const Mat<double>& M) {
    if (M.rows != M.cols) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Matrix must be square.");
    }

    int n = M.rows;
    int lda = n;
    int info = 0;

    // Allocate memory for a copy of the matrix
    double A[n * n];
    std::copy(M.data, M.data + n * n, A);

    // Perform Cholesky decomposition (LAPACKE_dpotrf)
    std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
    info = LAPACKE_dpotrf(LAPACK_COL_MAJOR, 'L', n, A, lda);
    std::cout << 2 << std::endl;
    if (info != 0) {
        // If Cholesky decomposition fails, use LU decomposition (LAPACKE_dgetrf)
        int* ipiv = new int[n];
        std::cout << 3 << std::endl;
        info = LAPACKE_dgetrf(LAPACK_COL_MAJOR, n, n, A, lda, ipiv);
        std::cout << 4 << std::endl;
        if (info != 0) {
            delete[] ipiv;
            throw std::runtime_error("LU decomposition failed.");
        }

        double ld = 0.0;
        double sign = 1.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            ld += std::log(std::abs(A[i * lda + i]));
            if (A[i * lda + i] < 0) {
                sign = -sign;
            }
        }

        // Compute the determinant of the permutation matrix
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            if (ipiv[i] != i + 1) {
                sign = -sign;
            }
        }

        delete[] ipiv;

        if (sign <= 0) {
            return -std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
        }

        return ld;
    }
    // If Cholesky decomposition is successful, compute the log determinant
    double ld = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        ld += std::log(A[i * lda + i]);
    }

    return 2.0 * ld;
}

TEST(TestMat, test_log_det) {
    const int N = 10;
    double data[] = {
        1.08994211e+03,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.01009670e+03,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, 5.86617865e+01, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  5.66102096e+03, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  -1.58955583e+09, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  -3.79986530e+09, 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        -1.62987547e+08, 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, -1.77108103e+06,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, 2.55362765e+02, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  1.51231951e+02}; 

    Mat<double> mat = {data, N, N};

    auto res = logdet_chol(mat);
    std::cout << "logdet = " << res << std::endl;
}

inline double logdet_chol_eig(Eigen::MatrixXd& M){
Mat<double> mm{.data = M.data(), .rows = M.rows(), .cols = M.cols()};
for(int i = 0; i < mm.rows; ++i){
    std::cout << "[ ";
    for(int j = 0; j < mm.cols; ++j){
        std::cout << mm.data[j * mm.rows + i] << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << "]" << std::endl;
}

return logdet_chol(mm);
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(test, m) {
  m.def("logdet", &logdet_chol_eig);
}

When calling logdet from python with
mat = np.diag([1089.942113770775, 1010.096696063498, 58.66178651250262, 5661.020957489456, -1589555826.24471, -3799865302.243693, -162987547.4735685, -1771081.02947091, 255.3627654232152, 151.2319507163488])
print(logdet(mat))

The program just stops after outputted "3" from my line "std::cout << 3 << std::endl;".
================================UPDATE================================
I changed dgetrf to dgetrf2 then it magically works, is it suggesting the C wrapper I am using is bugged?

Provide a [mcve]

"I tried "cout" everywhere..." Better would be a debugger. See what is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems

@user12002570 Debugging into C from python is kinda hell on earth, so I have sympathies.

Did you verify the matrix contents are what you expected with std::cout << M << std::endl?

I write a unit test in C++ this is great, please show it to us. It would be best  if you give a live example. Here are starting points for gtest or catch2. Now I see you are using LAPACK  and compiler explorer do not support this library :/.

Why you are using Eigen and LAPACK at the same time? Both are doing linear algebra, so have same functionality. IMO Eigen  is more user friendly.

Unrelated, but it appears that you're leaking A.

@PasserBy I found it a lot more convenient to make an executable with embedded Python interpreter that contains the Pybind-wrapped module as well. Then just have it exec some simple Python snippet to excercise the function in question. Much easier to deal with than a standalone interpreter and trying to debug code in a dynamically loaded library.

@DanMašek I thought only forms like double* A = new double[n*n]; leaks, it leaks too without new?

@Botje Yes, it seems everything was fine before LU decompose, and it breaks in the line info = LAPACKE_dgetrf(LAPACK_COL_MAJOR, n, n, A, lda, ipiv);, I failed to debug into C from python, let alone debug into fortran from C from python.

@MarekR I have updated my code, I am just using eigen for pybind

The comment applies to the code that was in the question at the time it was written. You got rid of the new 14 hours after I wrote it.

I tried cout everywhere If you are, maybe call cout.flush() each time.
